# Installing WebDeploy Service

Tags: iis-7.5

I'm stuggling with installing WebDeploy service on my development PC (Windows 7 Professional with IIS 7.5). Can someone give me the steps required to do that.

Update: I installed the Web Deployment Tool from WPI and verified that the web deployment service is running (I believe it's "Web Deployment Agent Service"), however, when I open IIS Manager I can't see the Management Service; as per my understanding it's were I configure web deployment.

If I'm missing something may be someone can tell me what it is and what to do next.

Thanks in advance,

TheBlueSky

Comment: You'll get a better answer if you full describe exactly what you've done, and what results and/or errors you see.

Comment: @TheBlueSky - if you've solved this for yourself, maybe you can help me at http://serverfault.com/questions/557539/how-to-configure-webdeploy-server-for-direct-publishing-from-visual-studio ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Management Service Delegation UI will only appear on Server SKUs, as only server SKUs have a functional Web Management Service (which delegation relates to). This will therefore never install on your Windows 7 client machine.

You can still enable Web Deploy publishing (for administrators only) using the Web Deployment Agent Service (msdepsvc) by starting the service if it is not started ("net start msdepsvc" on command line) and opening port 80 in the firewall for the service, as needed. There is no UI for this service.

If you need any direction on the right command line for the client or VS publishing options to use the Agent service, please post again on the IIS forums: http://forums.iis.net/1144.aspx

Hope that helps!
-Kristina

Comment: Thanks Kristina for the reply. Based on the information you provided I must be ready for the deployment as all the applications or services I need are installed and running; however, this is what I'm getting when trying to deploy from WebMatrix for example: [http://bit.ly/mpVxVD](http://bit.ly/mpVxVD)... what is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi TheBlueSky. I'm afraid WebMatrix is set up to use only the Web Management Service (WMSvc) for Web Deploy publishing and will not work with the agent service (msdepsvc). The destination server must be a server SKU with IIS7 or IIS7.5 (i.e. SKUs with functional WMSvc). If you really want to publish to this client machine, then you can still do so using the Web Deploy command line and the agent service - I'll post how to do this on the forum thread: http://forums.iis.net/t/1179465.aspx#1987891 (more space there).

Comment: Thanks Kristina. I'm marking this post as an answer to my question, but for anyone reading the question, please go to [http://forums.iis.net/t/1179465.aspx](http://forums.iis.net/t/1179465.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that finds this and is having trouble finding the Management Service Delegation option on Windows Server the issue is that you have to use the standalone Web Deploy installer and not the Web Platform Installer version and that you have to select some additional options in the standalone installer during installation.

When installing select custom install from the menu and make sure that the "IIS Deployment Hander" and "Management Services Delegation UI" options are selected.

Answer (score 0):

[Installing Web Deploy](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/421/installing-web-deploy/)

[Web Deploy](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/346/web-deploy/)

Web Deploy (Web Deployment Tool) is an IIS extension, containing essentially a set of tools and a managed framework for simplifying the deployment, management, synchronisation and migration of Web applications, sites, and even entire servers.

This link explains how to [Export a Package](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/514/export-a-package-through-iis-manager/) while this one how to [Import a Package](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/515/import-a-package-through-iis-manager/) using IIS Manager.

To access Web Deploy functionality you need to navigate to your site in IIS Manager (expand the Server node and the Sites node, then select the desired Site or Application), now right click on it, choose one of the entries from "Manage packages" sub-menu and follow the wizard. You need to do a Export operation on your dev PC and when all done do Import on your Server.

Comment: What the first article is saying is what I did already. Please re-read the question as I updated it with the steps I did previously.

Comment: @TheBlueSky: Updated my answer. I have not used console or synchronize whole server, just Export/Import functionality for the website.

Comment: The question wasn't about how to export and import an application. What I'm trying to achieve now is publishing an application (e.g. from Visual Studio or Web Matrix) to my IIS, from my dev machine or remotely... I just can't see the section where I can configure that in IIS.

Comment: @TheBlueSky: You question **was** and **still** reads _"I'm stuggling with installing WebDeploy service"_ and _"when I open IIS Manager I can't see the Management Service;"_. Now you have completely different question. You better start **New Question** to attract some attention providing exact details of what are you trying to achieve, your situation (e.g. which VS you are using; what type of app you're trying to deploy) etc -- exactly as @mfinni said. I think I gave you an answer for the original question.

Comment: **No**, this is **not** a new question, and **No**, you did **not** give me the answer to my original question. In order to be able to deploy anything to my IIS, I need to first configure the web deployment service (correct me if I'm wrong), and in order to configure this service, I need to access "Management Service Delegation"... **I still can't see the Management Service**; i.e. the one in this picture [Management Service Delegation](http://learn.iis.net/Content_Cache/516/Management_Service_Delegation.png).

Comment: Adding more detailed description of the problem from very beginning usually helps: http://forums.iis.net/p/1171432/1960329.aspx ; http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2010/04/22/Done28099t-Install-Web-Deployment-Tool-using-the-Web-Platform-Installer.aspx

Comment: The details were added as soon as I read mfinni comment and not recently. Am I stuggling? Sure, and here are few screen shots of what I did and still can't get it working: [IIS Management Service Setup](http://bit.ly/kVG5QD), [Installing WebDeploy](http://bit.ly/lhCK3m), [checking the services](http://bit.ly/j8e13a) and [IIS Manager](http://bit.ly/k7jkrs)... noticed the last screen shot? Where are "Management Service" and "Management Service Delegation"?